# Phonegap Build facebook Connect Plugin (android)

Tags: android, facebook, plugins, phonegap-build

I have a strange problem using the facebook plugin with phonegap build. 
It sounds like a certificate problem but I can't figure it out.

I tried the sample code found here : github.com/amirudin/pgb-fbconnect

I followed instructions in the readme.md file.

When I first start the android app and when I click on "login" button, everything works fine and I can connect myself to the facebook app.

Now, I hit the logout button. Ok again, it works.

But if I hit the login button again, I have a facebook error message : "invalid android_key_parameter. The key xxxxxxxxxxxxxx does not match any allowed key."

But the xxxxxx key in the message does not correspond to the key I've put in the facebook app config panel.

I have a little video of my problem here : [Dropbox video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/79ok2dv5r856dqm/20130807_130857.mp4)

I don't understand why it works fine during the first login and fail during the second one .... It seems that the second time, the signature change.

Help!!

I created a [github repo](https://github.com/cabrinoob/FbTest.git) if someone want to test it. You just have to change the APP_NAME and APP_ID in the config.xml and the APP_ID in index.html

It's very frustrating to have something which "almost" works.

Did you succeed in reproducing my bug/behavior ? (login + logout + login = fail)

Comment: That does look pretty weird. I would recommend you post about this issue on their GetSatisfaction site: http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/products/nitobi_phonegap_build

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing because of you are not using right keystore file, Signed key, and key algorithm. You will need to generate a hash of your Android key(s) and submit those to the Developers page on Facebook.

***If you are generating this hash on Windows (specifically 64 bit versions), please use version 0.9.8e or 0.9.8d of OpenSSL for Windows and not 0.9.8k.***

Once you download openssl, open the command prompt (cmd.exe) as an Administrator, then run the following command:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore [keystore_name].keystore -alias [alias_name] -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Please note the `alias_name`, and keep all passwords `andriod`

Now, go to your phonegap account >> edit account >> Click on signing keys tab >> Click 'add a key...' and supply the following info:

```
Title - anything

Alias - alias_name that you have given while generating the keystore file.
```

Then, create a new hash key using the keystore file that you generated and then update that hash key in your facebook app.

Use below command to generate hash key.

**keytool -exportcert -alias [alias_name] -keystore [keystore_filename.keystore] | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64**

That should be it!