# Phonegap build - Facebook connect plugin - Invalid android_key parameter error

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I'm running example code (found below) through phonegap build to produce an android apk.

https://github.com/phonegap-build/FacebookConnect/blob/master/example/Simple/index.html

When I try to log into facebook through the app on an android device (with the facebook app installed), I get this error:

> Invalid android_key parameter J4INwYsuTyQ_LJc1d3WZ2HReg7M does not match any allowed android key. Configure your app key hashes at http://developers.facebook.com/apps/'app id'

I have copy-pasted this key into the key hashes section of my app's android settings but it still throws the same error when I try to log in using the app.

**How can I get this app to log into facebook successfully?**

OR: What is another way to enable an android app to log into facebook using phonegap?

Here are some things I have done:

- #### In my facebook app's settings:

  - Set 'Package name' to the 'widget id' found in my phonegap config.xml.
  - Set 'Class name' to the Package name with '.ProjectActivity' appended to it.
  - Enabled 'Single Sign on' and disabled 'Deep linking'.
  - Made the app open to the public (through the 'Status & Review' section.
- #### In my phonegap config.xml (found in the /www directory in phonegap project):

  - Entered APP_ID as the ID found in my facebook app dashboard
  - Entered APP_NAME as the 'Namespace' found in my facebook app settings
- #### In my phonegap build app settings:

  - Made a keystore (using this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19315975/1696114) and used it to generate a release apk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully made an app which can log into facebook by using the phonegap-facebook-plugin and by building my cordova/phonegap project locally.

I made a new cordova project and added the android platform for this project, following the instructions here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_overview_index.md.html#Overview

In doing this I discovered I had made my previous project using an older cordova version (3.1) un-intentionally and that I hadn't installed the cordova command line interface. There may have been other issues with the way I made my first project.

I then added the phonegap-facebook-plugin found here: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin using this command (from my project location):

```
    cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin.git --variable       APP_ID="xxxxxxxxxxxxx" --variable APP_NAME=“xxxxxxxx”
```

(replacing APP_ID value with my facebook app id and APP_NAME value with my app's namespace).

I then replaced my index.html with the example index file found at the phonegap-facebook-plugin github page + /blob/master/example/Simple/index.html  (replacing the app_id value with my app id).

I then ran the app straight to my android device using:

```
    cordova run android
```

In this app, I'm able to use the interface provided by the example to login, post to my own or friends' walls etc. Using this new project (with updated cordova version) I may be able to use phonegap build but I haven't tried yet.

Thanks to Dato' Mohammad Nurdin for the suggestion to use this plugin.

Comment: In fact I used the same steps and I failed, can you please shared the eclipse project with me

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use facebook phonegap plugin as your authentication.

Download and install into your cordova project.

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin

Use this command to install it.

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin.git --variable APP_ID="xxxxxxxxxxxxx" --variable APP_NAME=“xxxxxxxx”
```

Then setup your facebook app here:

http://developers.facebook.com/apps/

Then make sure you have this script in your project.

```
cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js
facebook-js-sdk.js
```

After that, paste this code into your main script

```
if ((typeof cordova == 'undefined') && (typeof Cordova == 'undefined')) alert('Cordova variable does not exist. Check that you have included cordova.js correctly');
if (typeof CDV == 'undefined') alert('CDV variable does not exist. Check that you have included cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js correctly');
if (typeof FB == 'undefined') alert('FB variable does not exist. Check that you have included the Facebook JS SDK file.');
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
    //alert('auth.login event');
});
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
    //alert('auth.logout event');
});
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.sessionChange', function(response) {
    //alert('auth.sessionChange event');
});
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {
    //alert('auth.statusChange event');
});

function getSession() {
    alert("session: " + JSON.stringify(FB.getSession()));
}

function getLoginStatus() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status == 'connected') {
            alert('logged in');
        } else {
            alert('not logged in');
        }
    });
}
var friendIDs = [];
var fdata;

function logout() {
    FB.logout(function(response) {
        alert('logged out');
        window.location.replace("#login");
    });
}

function login() {
    FB.login(

    function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            alert('logged in');
            FB.api('/me', function(me) {
                if (me.id) {
                                    localStorage.id = me.id;
                    localStorage.email = me.email;
                    localStorage.name = me.name;
                    window.location.replace("#home");
                }
                else {
                    alert('No Internet Connection. Click OK to exit app');
                    navigator.app.exitApp();
                }
            });
        } else {
            alert('not logged in');
        }
    }, {
        scope: "email"
    });
}

document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
    try {
        //alert('Device is ready! Make sure you set your app_id below this alert.');
        FB.init({
            appId: "appid",
            nativeInterface: CDV.FB,
            useCachedDialogs: false
        });
        document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = "";
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
}, false);
```

use `login()` to login . Enjoy!!

Comment: The code you suggest to use seems to be very similar to the example on the plugin's github page, except a few things are missing which would make it work like a reference to the cordova.js file and a div with class="data".