# Facebook app settings on PhoneGap application

Tags: facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins, facebook-apps

I have a phonegap application that uses the main [facebook-plugin](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin) for connecting. I'm also using the phonegap build to directly get the apk/ipa without generating an android/ios project.

Inside the facebook for developers, however, I have to complete some settings for my application that seem to require more than the simple phonegap build. I saw some tutorial in generating the hash key for an android app, but, what should I complete into the "Class Name" field(the activity that facebook will launch) since I don't have any class in my javascript-phonegap code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have provided screenshots of the config.xml path and the configuration where you will find the package id. `

> If you are using cordova from command-line, the default activity class for Cordova android application is CordovaApp.

So for in this case your configuration in Facebook developer should be like this.

```
Package Name: com.phonegap.helloworld
Default Activity Class Name: com.phonegap.helloworld.CordovaApp
```

You need to update the package name as per the entry you have in the config.xml

[image]

> If you are building your app using the Adobe Phonegap Build Service,in that case the default activity name is generated by CamelCase notation of your application name.
>   So `Default Activity Test` becomes `DefaultActivityTest`

So your configuration in Facebook developer should look like this.

```
Package Name: com.phonegap.randomPackage
Default Activity Class Name: com.phonegap.randomPackage.DefaultActivityTest
```

[image]

You can decompile your apk from the site below:

http://www.decompileandroid.com.

Choose the static version(the flash version was not working) and after uploading,you can see the decompiled AndroidManifest.xml file.

This is what I got after decompiling my application apk.

http://www.decompileandroid.com/complete/182864?key=ecb3cec5a9b1418afe5d67f7151b518f

[image]

Comment: I already knew about the package name, I didn't know the default activity is CordovaApp, tho. 

That's what I needed, I hope this is correct. I will let this open for another day or so, just to see if there is another opinion.

Comment: also, I saw a post here some time ago that one has put as a class name 'package'.ProjectActivity . Can you confirm that this has changed?

Comment: I also found the post 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22576209/phonegap-build-facebook-connect-plugin-invalid-android-key-parameter-error

Comment: @Radu, I have edited my answer for cordova app build from command-line and PhoneGap build both.

Comment: @SurajitSarkar THANKS A LOT. ONLY SOLUTION SO FAR ON THE WEB

Answer (score 0):

If you create android application means, you specified your "activity name" during project creation.That name is your class name.

**Enter package name: com.example.proj** and 
**Enter class name: Your project activity name** and
Enter your key hash

Comment: I think you forget about the cordova/phonegap thing? I do not create the project, it just builds me the apk.