# Phonegap Cordova Login with Facebook

Tags: android, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

I'm new in Phonegap and i'm trying to add Facebook login in my Cordova application, i tried Plugin and Facebook SDK for Javascript.

Plugin: https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4

Facebook JavaScript SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web

In both the sdk and javascript plugin, I encountered difficulties.

Plugin:

```
The key hash does not match any stored key hashes
```

Facebook SDK JS:

```
Unable to load URL: The domain for this URL is not included in the application domains. In order to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains to the Application Domains field in the application settings.
```

I tried to add localhost as my domain but does not work, and tried to create a hash in Windows, I generated the hash and added it to my facebook app but still appear the same error.

Anyone has idea?

```
<!--Version Phonegap-->
<preference name="cordova-ios" version="4.5.4" />
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-8.0.0" />
```

Facebook Plugin config.xml:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-facebook4" spec="~4.2.1">
    <variable name="APP_ID" value="XXXXXXXXX" />
    <variable name="APP_NAME" value="YYYYYY" />
</plugin>
```

Facebook Plugin Login:

```
const permissions = new Array("email","public_profile");

        facebookConnectPlugin.login(permissions, function (userData) {
            console.log("UserInfo: ", userData);
        },
          function loginError(error) {
            console.error(error)
          }
        );
```

Facebook SDK JS:

```
FB.login(function (response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                // Logged into your app and Facebook.
            } else {
                // The person is not logged into this app or we are unable to tell. 
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to resolve:

```
The key hash does not match any stored key hashes
```

I setup my Facebook App as Android Platform and set my package name with (config.xml):

```
widget id="com.XXXX.YYY.ZZZ"
```

And my Class Name, i follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26600976/facebook-app-settings-on-phonegap-application) and used http://www.javadecompilers.com/result.

To generate my hash, i follow [Muhammad Omar ElShourbagy solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32915985/how-does-ionic-cordova-generate-hash-key).

Everything works fine.

Comment: How did you get around the Unable to load URL: The domain for this URL is not included in the application domains. In order to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains to the Application Domains field in the application settings.
 issue?